# AS3: rotation VS rotationZ

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, rotation

Are there significant differences between tweening an object's rotation property VS its rotationZ property? Does rotation apply a Matrix, while rotationZ applies a Matrix3D? Are there differences in performance? If the object is a vector sprite, does it remain a vector with rotation, but become a bitmap with rotationZ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the object would remain a vector both ways. Generally, I think it comes down to deciding whether you want to do things in 2D or 3D, as some 2D properties are overwritten if you're using 3D properties. I'd recommend sticking to one or the other for any given object.

To my knowledge, there is no other difference, really.

Comment: Yes, the object would remain a vector, but what I meant to say was would it be rendered as a bitmap? It seems that sometimes if you use rotationX, or rotationY, or rotationZ, your image will become blurry because of some bitmap filtering.

Comment: Hmm, interesting thought. I know the Flash Professional IDE gives control over whether you're using vector or bitmap rendering. What IDE are you on?